# How to schedule my kafka events to be produced at quarter past and quarter to the hour?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a service that uses kafka streams, and has a local kafka store. I store kafka records(events) with a timestamp in this store, and then have a punctuator that iterates through the kafka store every half hour. If the current timestamp value is larger than the timestamp value of the event in the kafka store, I remove this event from the kafka store and produce it to a topic.

I would like to modify this approach as instead of doing this iteration through the kafka store at regular intervals, I want it to always do this at quarter past the current hour or quarter to the next hour. Example. Only iterate through the kafka store and produce eligible events at 12:15, 12:45, 1:15, 1:45, .... and so on. How should I go about doing this? Does Kafka have something similar to the punctuator that we can configure to check at certain times, instead of certain intervals?

Comment: You can still schedule with lower frequency (like each minute) and just check within your code if it's time to perform actual work. Beside that, you might be interested in: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7699

Comment: Thanks @MatthiasJ.Sax , yes I am doing the approach you suggested. The punctuator will be set to punctuate every 1 minute. At that time, I'll check the actual time and if its the desired time, I will continue with the process.